# Difference between '01' and '1' in a JavaScript date

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the dates '2015-10-01' and '2015-10-1' in JavaScript?

```
new Date('2015-10-1')
```

This returns `'Thu Oct 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0300'`

```
new Date('2015-10-01')
```

Returns `'Wed Sep 30 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300'`

Comment: first one gives me "Invalid Date = $1"..

Comment: Both gives me `Thu Oct 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300`

Comment: @ergonaut test in another browser, in firefox gives me "Invalid" too, but in chrome not.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak yes? I test in several pages and return diferent result

Comment: Timezones. Must be them. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but is only date, no time

Comment: Maybe a bug in JS's date pattern parsing?

Comment: you should never use this Date constructor. It will take absolutely anything and try to create a date for it, even it is nonsense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What I see after executing locally is

- Date in **local timezone**
- Date in **UTC**

As per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), `Date.parse` will assume the date to be UTC format if it has complete `DD` else it will assume in local timezone format.

---

**Detailed explanation regarding month change:** (comments)

`new Date('2015-10-1')` when you execute this statement output is *'Thu Oct 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0300'*. i.e. its your local time and it is GMT -3hrs.

But when you execute the `new Date('2015-10-01')` the output is *'Wed Sep 30 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0300'* which is in UTC time. i.e. 3hrs minus from your local time.

So it is *1st Oct midnight -3hrs*, which is previous day's 21hrs. i.e. Sep 30 21hrs.

Comment: Good find.  This is so weird, safari is more strict and doesn't allow it.  So it's a Vendor specific thing.

Comment: Results from my chrome console: `new Date('2015-10-01') // Thu Oct 01 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)` - using local time.

Comment: @ergonaut Yep: the ECMAScript spec *requires* specific standard date formats, but also *permits* implementations to support whatever additional  formats they want ([ES5 15.9.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2)). Since this isn't a standard format, it's up to the vendor's implementation to decide whether and how to support it.

Comment: @rajuGT if I use '.getUTCMonth()' the result is correct, but if I use .getMonth() the result is incorrect, but the 'fail format' works. I'm not clear because I not use time, but change the date of utc (thanks for the reply)

Comment: @Nacho When it is 9:00 PM at your house, it is midnight at the beginning of the next day in Greenwich, England (GMT/UTC time). When this falls on a month boundary, your house (in GMT-3:00) and Greenwich (in GMT+0 / UTC) are in different months.

Comment: @Nacho updated my answer. hope it gives more clarity.

Comment: @rajuGT: you too are confused. He's in "GMT-3". So GMT is 3 hours **ahead** of his time, not behind. The edit you made just adds more confusion, not clarity. :)

Comment: oops! sorry yeah. thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: I understand! Thank you very much, and sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: This is good to know. I didnt find anything like this in the docs.

Answer (score 6):

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
new Date(dateString)
```

> **dateString**
>
> A string representing an RFC2822 or [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).

`'2015-10-1'` is neither of the supported formats and, as promised, you get unexpected results (whereas `'2015-10-01'` is a valid ISO 8601 date).

Comment: But in this case the '2015-10-1' are the correct result (thanks for the reply)

Comment: Yes, `2015-10-01` conforms to ISO-8601 format.

Comment: Sorry, I meant '2015-10-1' are the correct result

Comment: @Nacho It is correct for your local time zone, but not to UTC time. Date formats that comply to the standard date format are always localized to the UTC timezone. Your non-standard format is localized to your timezone, unlike a standard-formatted date.

Comment: @Nacho: No, it's not. Try appending `.toGMTString()` to them ( `new Date('2015-10-01').toGMTString()`)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev now I understand! Thank you very much for the answers, and sorry for the newbie question (and for my bad english).

Comment: @Nacho: dealing with dates and timezones is always a pain, even for veterans :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see, thank you very much again :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because JavaScript is expecting a certain amount of characters in the date string.

You have two formats here:

```
(YYYY-MM-DD)
```

and

```
(YYYY-MM-D)
```

I am surprised that the second is returning anything at all, as it doesn't seem to fit any valid [JavaScript Date String format](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp). If it is returning as you say it is, then JavaScript is likely interpreting it as something other than Years, Months and Days.

Comment: Note that this behavior is not *too* surprising: the ECMAScript spec permits implementations to support any date formats they please. Only standard date formats are required, but arbitrary additional formats are allowed. ([ES5 15.9.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2): "If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.")

Comment: But in this case the '2015-10-1' are the correct result (thanks for the reply)