# JS Date() - Leading zero on days

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox

A leading zero for the day within a string seems to break the Javascript Date object in Chrome. There are also some inconsistencies between browsers, since Firefox handles the leading zero correctly, but fails when the zero is not included. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/3m6ovh1f/3/

`Date('2015-11-01'); // works in Firefox, not in Chrome`

`Date('2015-11-1'); // works in Chrome, not in Firefox`

Why? Is there a good way to work around/with the leading zero?

Please note, the strings are coming from MySQL via AJAX and all dates will contain the leading zero, and I can fix this by formating the dates server-side. What format would work the best?

**EDIT**

Just to specify what my problem was, it looks like Chrome is applying a time zone to the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, which reverts the Nov. 1st date back to the Oct. 31st date (because of my EDT local time).

Comment: `Date('2015-11-01')` works fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between '01' and '1' in a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955560/difference-between-01-and-1-in-a-javascript-date)

Comment: [Here is the spec with the standard JavaScript date format.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

Comment: @rajuGT That doesn't tell me how to fix the problem; those answers just tell me what I already know.

Comment: @Pointy It looks like a full date, including time and time zone, could be the best format. Thanks for the documentation.

Comment: @Siphon See, if we are using dateString which is not mentioned in the specs, a browser may support as additional feature, but you cannot expect it to be in all browser. It recommends to use which is defined in specs. Check this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse they have mentioned clearly and also the links for specs.

**A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).**

Comment: @rajuGT According to your linked document, the string '2015-11-01' would match the ISO 6801 date format. I'm thinking the full ISO 6801 date AND time would be better, at least for my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [ECMA-262 (5.1)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2):

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format (15.9.1.15). **If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.**

The date/time string format as described in 15.9.1.15 is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`. It can also be a shorter representation of this format, like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

`2015-11-1` is *not* a valid date/time string for Javascript (note it's `YYYY-MM-D` and not `YYYY-MM-DD`). Thus, the implementation (browser) is able to do *whatever it wants* with that string. It can attempt to parse the string in a different format, or it can simply say that the string is an invalid date. Chrome chooses the former (see [`DateParser::Parse`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/dateparser-inl.h&sq=package:chromium&l=16)) and attempts to parse it as a "legacy" date. Firefox seems to choose the latter, and refuses to parse it.

Now, your claim that `new Date('2015-11-01')` doesn't work in Chrome is incorrect. As the string conforms to the date/time string format, Chrome *must* parse it to be specification compliant. In fact, I just tried it myself -- it works in Chrome.

So, what are your options here?

1. Use the *correct* date/time format (i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` or some extension of it).
2. Use the `new Date (year, month, date)` constructor, i.e. `new Date(2015, 10, 1)` (months go from 0-11) in this case.

Whichever option is up to you, but there *is* a date/time string format that all specification compliant browsers should agree on.

Comment: Ah, yes! The key thing here is what Chrome does for the `YYYY-MM-DD` format versus the `YYYY-MM-D` format; one applies the time zone, while one does not. In your link, there was a comment stating `(following Safari, ISO actually demands local time)`, which means ISO output versus legacy output is expected to be different.

Comment: Although, having Chrome apply a time zone to a date (not a date and time) is quite a pain and not very intuitive. I'm just going to add the time and time zone to prevent any further 'legacy' issues in browsers.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, why not use unix timestamps instead? In JavaScript, you would would multiply the timestamp value by 1000,
e.g

```
var _t = { time: 1446220558 };
var _d = new Date( _t.time*1000 );
```

Test in your browser console:

```
new Date( 14462205581000 );
// prints Fri Oct 30 2015 11:55:58 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

There's a little benefit in it as well (if data comes via JS) - you'd save 2 bytes on every date element '2015-10-30' VS 1446220558 :)

Comment: This works well with minimal extra effort. I like the fact that I won't have to worry about specifying a date format, and it seems to work across all browsers.

Comment: This would seem to introduce *more* confusion -- I don't believe that most programmers can identify the value of a Unix timestamp in their head.

Comment: The solution was accepted, with readability not being one of the criteria. Second best is to use YYYY-MM-DD (which MySQL uses) and all is well.

Comment: I ended up opting to use the full `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` format for the sake of cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Sigh ... well - for _readability_ I do agree - the long format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` works best.